# svelte-oidc loose authentication on page refresh

Tags: javascript, svelte, openid-connect, sveltekit

Ism having trouble keeping my user authenticated with svelte-oidc.
I do exactly like the example but when I reload the page I need to sign-in again.
Here's my code :

**+layout.svelte**

```
<script>
import {OidcContext,LoginButton,RefreshTokenButton,isAuthenticated} from '@dopry/svelte-oidc';
</script>

<OidcContext
 issuer="https://dev-hvw40i79.auth0.com"
 client_id="aOijZt2ug6Ovgzp0HXdF23B6zxwA6PaP"
 redirect_uri="https://darrelopry.com/svelte-oidc/"
 post_logout_redirect_uri="https://darrelopry.com/svelte-oidc/"
 metadata={metadata}
 >
  <LoginButton>Login</LoginButton>
  <RefreshTokenButton>RefreshToken</RefreshTokenButton><br />
  <pre>isAuthenticated: {$isAuthenticated}</pre>
        <slot></slot>
</OidcContext>
```

I found this issue but it seems that the problem was not really there..
[Issue](https://github.com/dopry/svelte-oidc/issues/9#issuecomment-736105888)

The thing is when I click again on the login button it works without me needing to fill in my credentials (looks like it uses my local storage to signin).
So my idea was to silently call the login method used [there](https://github.com/dopry/svelte-oidc/blob/bbd4cfc70f9f9e73ce16777fc293493d4b42d8be/src/components/LoginButton.svelte#L16) but I don't nkow how to do it with svelte.. I was trying to do it in **+layout.js** but I don't know where to find the context (first argument of login).

I'm using this lib all wrong or is there any solution I'm missing ?